# Why do i need to execute sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 command again after every shutdown/hibernation?

Tags: linux, port, linux-mint

To upload sketch to an arduino need to execute following command:

`sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`.

I think it is because to identify the port and list it in system.But i need to execute it after every time i shutdown or hibernate my PC.But why? and how can i avoid this.  I want to write the command only once and not after every shutdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you get when you `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0` ?

Many of these devices are owned by a group specific to the use of that hardware, like `dialout` for serial ports.  Typically, that specialized group has write permission on that port.  If you add your user to that group, you won't have to keep changing permissions.

Your changes to files in `/dev` aren't persistent because the directory is generated dynamically each time your system starts up; if you run: `mount | grep ' /dev'` you will see that a virtual filesystem like `udev` (it depends on your distro) is mounted, not an actual device like `/dev/sda1`.

Use something like `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` to add yourself to that group, then log out and log in again to activate the change.

Comment: While the answer is correct, and helpful, it is in answer to a question that is Off-Topic on StackOverflow. The question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). I gave you the helpful vote, but in the future, please try and insure the question is answered on the appropriate site where it is likely to be found by others with a similar problem or question.

Comment: Yes, your answer is indeed correct, and although not "Programming" related, I found it right off the bat when I entered the error message in my browser. :) Thanks Jeff!